# (Typescript) How to instanciate object literal that contain a field of array type?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object-literal

I have this error with the following code :

**error TS2693: 'any' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here**

```
    let modelYaml = this.readFileModel('models/model.yml');

    // Build input model
    let inputModel = {
        elements: any[] = new Array<any>(),  <--Error occured on this line
        relations: any[]= new Array<any>()   <--Error occured on this line
    }
    inputModel.elements.push(modelYaml); <- Error occured
```

modelYaml is of type object (function readFileModel return any)

**tsconfig.json**

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "tsconfig",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

I had a hard time to find a code sample in typescript that describe object literal with array.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You put types in wrong places.. `let inputModel: { elements: any[],  relations: any[] } = { elements: [], relations: [] }`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks ! Probem solved. You can answer my question and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `new Array<any>()`, use `[]`. TypeScript will infer the literal type based upon type definition on the variable.

Comment: Hello Michael. If I write only what you said I've got a problem of "never" type. Problem is solved with @Aleksey L. comments (which contain your idea). Thanks anyway !

Comment: Fantastic! Oof yeah I forgot, entire variable definition before any assignment.